# Is it possible: Bypassing XSLT conversion with script

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt, outlook

Looking for advice on a project requiring dynamic html documents (Not embedded in a browser).

I am a newb to XML and am having a hard time understanding the XSLT transformations.  To further complicate things, I am working in the context of MS Office Suite email automation.

I *want* to be able to construct dynamic emails that come from different xsl/html templates that can be merged together and customized per recipient.

I have ventured down the path of creating XSLT in MS Word, but it seems there are more than a few hurdles.

1. I am a VBA programmer, and only have the Express Version of Visual Studio.
2. The documentation for manipulating XML through Word's VBA language is not that good.
3. The XSLT produced by Word is mind bending to look at.  I can see a typical XSL file and get the gist of whats going.  Can't say the same for Word versions. (*I came across an article a while back where an author of the O'Reilly book Office XML 2003 bashing MS for their XML programming support*)
4. I am working with flat file XML exports from MS Access.  Getting them converted to the hierarchies represented in the templates seems tough.
5. I don't have much time to construct this feature of the application :(

So with all that in mind, and drawing inspiration from [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/07/martin-fowler-hates-xslt-too.html)
link, is it feasible to export my flat file xml and generate the dynamic html files with a scripting language like ruby, etc?

If so, are there any guidelines and/or resources for this approach?

I was thinking something like...

- translating the XML file into a native ruby data structure.
- calling out variables in the HTML templates like `<p>Greetings <div id="recipient"></div>!</p>` (This would be the parent node, attached to a 'recipient' hash, array, etc)
- then taking table definitions like `<table class="my-template">
  <tr>
  <th id="action-item">Action Item</th>
  <th id="due-date">Due Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>`  and constructing the full table based on the `class` and `id` attributes available in the template.

So good idea, bad idea?  Not trying to be lazy, but didn't want to go down the MS Office - XSLT - .Net framework - limited VBA documentation route without exploring possible alternatives.

Also not dissing XLST, but I'm not sure I have time to learn all that is necessary given the projects circumstances and time frame.

If you think I'm wrong, please let me know!

Comment: Could you explain briefly in what context Word actually produces XSLT and what it contains? So far I'm only familiar with fact that it uses XML as one of its storage formats.

Comment: Here is an example provided by MS.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872374(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of mixing up one X-technology with the other.

**XML** is a markup language that is meant to represent your data in a structured and meaningful way.

**XSLT** provides a means for transforming XML documents. Of course it is rather confusing that XSLT stylesheets are themselves written in XML. But there is an obvious advantage of this: if XSLT is in XML, you can easily transform XSLT into another XSLT. XSLT stylesheets are read by an XSLT processor (like Saxon) and applied to an XML document. Also, a "template" is present only in XSLT, not in XML files in general.

So, I would say that you are confusing XSLT with XML. MS Word can store files as **XML** (OpenXML) and that's what you've been looking at. Of course you can get any information out of these OpenXML files, but if you are new to XSLT I suggest you start with something simpler.

XSLT is a good choice to transform XML into HTML, though. If you know Ruby (or Python, or Perl, or Java...), there are XML functions too, for example DOM.

Besides, this is a rather conceptual question - whereas SO is better at helping you with discrete programming issues. Try something and share your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  After some more research I think that the number of conversions I would need (transform to hierarchy, transform to html, etc) means that I really just need to learn more about XSLT.